# Passing parameters in hosted chef in windows

Tags: windows, parameters, chef-infra

I am working in **Hosted Chef** environment in **windows**.We have a UI from where we run Chef Scripts.When there are no parameters to be passed we just select the script to be executed and run the batch file with knife commands in the background execute the scripts.
Now I need to pass parameters dynamically to the recipes.I have tried adding attributes in the attribute file.It is working fine.But each time, I need to download and change the attributes and upload the recipes to chef server and run it using batch file which is quite tedious and time consuming.
Is there any other way to fulfil this requirement ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add attributes to the chef-client call directly.  That kills the "when there are no parameters to be passed", but it does allow you to get attributes in at run-time.  There are two ways to do this.  Either you pass in a file with the `-j` option (which might work nicely with your GUI), or you can hack it.  This hack works with linux, not sure how you'd do it with windows, but I'm sure there is a similar option.

```
echo '{ "myjson": "here" }' | chef-client -j /dev/stdin
```

Or if you are using `winrm` to run `chef-client` something like this:

```
knife winrm -m ipaddress 'echo "{ \"param\":\"test\"}" | chef-client -c c:/ chef/client.rb -j /dev/sdin' -m -x Administrator -P '@@@@@@'
```

That assumes you have a linux machine on the other end.  Otherwise, I'm not sure how to read stdin as if it were a file.  `-j /dev/stdin` probably won't work for windows clients.

Comment: I am executing this command in remote machine knife winrm -m ipaddress  'chef-client -c c:/chef/client.rb' -m -x Administrator  -P '*******'.when i give -j the json file should be present in remote machine  or the workstation.

Comment: the file should be present on the machine where the knife command actually executes.

Comment: Thanks Tejay..Sorry to bother again.I am very new to chef
When I execute
knife winrm -m ipaddress  'chef-client -c c:/
chef/client.rb' -m -x Administrator  -P '@@@@@@' -j '{"param":"test"}'
Error: invalid option: -j
USAGE: knife winrm QUERY COMMAND (options)
It is throwing error as no -j option.Plz help

Comment: In this case the `-j` is an argument to the `chef-client` command, not the `winrm` command.  I've updated my answer to include my best guess on the syntax.  (I can't confirm it as I don't use windows)

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables in your recipe code, but that is often very brittle. You can also read a local file either via the `-j` option mentioned above or by just opening and reading the file yourself in your recipe code. There is no direct way to pass parameters to recipes, and it generally indicates you are doing something non-convergent.